# Does a UICollectionView use its dataSource under the hood when cellForItem(at:) is called?

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

So UICollectionViews expose the method `cellForItem(at:)` which allows us to access a cell contained in a collection view.

We also know the collectionView uses its datasource's `collectionView(_:cellForItemAt:)` method in order to create and configure its cells.

However, using a breakpoint it appears `collectionView(_:cellForItemAt:)` is never called when calling `cellForItem(at:)`. What's going on here? Doesn't the collection view have to access its data source in order to know what cell to return? Is it caching all its cells at some point and if it is when is that caching happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`cellForItem(at:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionview/1618088-cellforitem) returns `nil` if a cell is not onscreen, so there is no need for it to call `collectionView(_:cellForItemAt:)` to get the cell.  It simply returns the cell if it is onscreen, and `nil` otherwise.